# I Rooted My Phone and Uninstalled Google Play Service

Tags: google-play-store

Even though I was warned, I went and uninstalled Google Play and Services because I've been using iMobile for my app store as I didn't think I needed them any more. Guess I was wrong because now iMobile won't open.

Comment: Well, there are a lot of services that requires the use of Google PlayServices app for working but I couldn't understand why Imobile isn't working anyway maybe you should try installing [Google PlayServices](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-6-6-03-1681564-876-apk/) back to see if installing it fixes the problem.

Comment: Follow the link if you want Google Play back 


http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117097/error-application-not-installed-when-trying-to-install-google-play-services-ap/117132#117132

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem few months back. Then what I did was:

I used a second, identical device (running the same Android version), and from there transferred all the components I had accidentally uninstalled on the first one, using some sort of apk sender application.

Comment: This answer is very hard to read and understand. what is "some sort of apk sender application"? How (and what) did you transfer "components you uninstalled"?