# Error: Application not installed, when trying to install Google Play Services APK

Tags: installation, google-play-services

I'm using XOLO A500 running Android 4.0.4. Initially, it was showing this error:

[image: IMG: Google Play Services error]

Then I tried installing Google Play Services through APK file(that was solution on many sites), but I am getting the error "Can't install Google play services":

[image: IMG: Can't install Google play services]

I rooted the  device, and  accidentally, my friend deleted it.

Comment: What app? What device model? Why your device came with no Google apps? Please elaborate.

Comment: @xangua Just updated question, check it out

Comment: if your any other friend have the same model phone , you can then share the apk file of googlePlayService and install, otherwise you can factory reset your phone which restore the system app..!

Answer (score 1):

1. Download **[System Apps Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.traber.systemappsinstaller&hl=en)** APK file and install it in your phone
2. Download recent version of **Google Play Services** app's APK
3. Install it as a system app by using **System Apps Installer**

**Note**: Incorrect use of **System Apps Installer** will harm your phone

Comment: can you explain 3rd step in detail ?

Comment: Go through this [link](http://www.androidgalaxys.net/migliori-app-galaxy-s/installare-un-qualsiasi-programma-come-app-di-sistema-con-system-apps-installer/); Translate the web page to **English** for readability